# I was trying to add expo-google-app-auth to my app but I'm getting this error expo-app-auth.authAsync is not available on ios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```
async function signInWithGoogleAsync() {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: androidClientId,
        iosClientId: iosClientId,
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
      });
  
      if (result.type === 'success') {
        return result.accessToken;
      } else {
        return { cancelled: true };
      }
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

error :

```
[Error: The method or property expo-app-auth.authAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
```